# Can I run Grunt/Gulp on my PHP 5.4 cartridge?

Tags: npm, openshift

I love the idea of OpenShift but I want to be able to run a JavaScript task runner on deployment.

I've noticed NPM is available but whenever I try to install my package.json file or `npm install grunt`, I get the following error:

```
Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

Is there a way to get this working on a PHP 5.4 cartridge?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible... although it would be rather difficult. The reason is being is because when a cartridge is deployed to a gear, there are config scripts executed to setup things like environment variables, runtime paths, etc. So you'll need to take some of the actions listed in the [NodeJs cartridge](https://github.com/Coolhand/origin-server/blob/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-nodejs/bin/control) and put them in a [action hook](http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_user_guide.html#action-hooks). Once thats all said and done you should be able to get that working.