# Installing grunt on Openshift (without Node cartridge)

Tags: gruntjs, openshift

I would like to install grunt and grunt-cli to my OpenShift deployment (which is a Python 2.7 cartridge).

I have created a package.json file as follows:

```
{
  "author": "--",
  "name": "--",
  "version": "0.3.0",
  "homepage": "--",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
      "grunt": "~0.4.5",
      "grunt-cli" : "~0.1.13",
      "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.5.0",
      "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
      "grunt-html2js": "^0.2.9",
      "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.0",
      "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.7.0",
      "grunt-index-html-template": "^0.2.5",
      "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1"
  }
}
```

However, after SSHing into the server post deployment, grunt is not installed. My questions are:

1. requirements.json is more of a Node thing. Therefore, is it that OpenShift ignores this file because I am not using Node (even though NPM is installed).
2. If 1 is correct, how do I go about installing grunt? (I've tried running 'npm install -g grunt' both via SSH and in an action hook script, but the fails due to lack or permissions).

This guy had the same issue ([Can I run Grunt/Gulp on my PHP 5.4 cartridge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933020/can-i-run-grunt-gulp-on-my-php-5-4-cartridge)) but I couldn't find what I needed in the answer.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to run `scl enable nodejs010` in your `./action-hook/start` command to enable a specific software collection in your gear. Hopefully that helps!